# Как использовать angularjs  с SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Добрый день.

Покажите, пожалуйста, простой пример, как использовать angularjs с SignalR.
Везде примеры с jquery, а хочется данные держать в ангуляре и чтоб из сервера передавались сразу в объектную модель ангуляра.

И другой вопрос: как из jquery функции изменить значение в модели ангуляра?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите вот [сюда](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/-Katana-Web-API-SignalR-ba9c44f1), там есть подробный пример. Или [здесь](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-web-application-with-e57d6345) на английском.